# sql server: is it possible to convert 1,123 to number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a field that is a `varchar` and the string is stored as `"1,223"` or `"23,342,234"`

they have comas!

is it possible to read them as `numbers`?

i dont like any of these answers. in mysql reading a varchar `1,123` and converting it to a number was no problem at all.

Comment: The below answers are correct. However, if this is a database for some sort of application, why not massage the values coming in (ie when you UPDATE, or INSERT), just do the ',' stripping there. instead of trying to fix the data as you get it out, fix it as it goes in.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i should have put that as an answer. =)

Comment: Take a look at martin clayton's approach and my stress testing results.

Comment: @jenny, rather than just saying "i dont like any of these answers", perhaps explain why? Also, Sql Server isn't MySql, you'll kinda have to get used to that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the Windows regional configuration settings AFAIK.

Comment: can u elaborate on this please?

Comment: it has nothing to do with Windows regional configuration. the other answers are correct.

Comment: The commas aren't being used as decimal separators.

Comment: My bad. At first glance I thought they were decimal separators.

Answer (score 6):

You could go via the MONEY datatype:

```
CAST( CAST( value AS MONEY ) AS INT )
```

When casting a VARCHAR to MONEY thousands separators *are* [allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx).  Also, implicit cast from MONEY to other numeric types is allowed, so you might be able to get away with

```
CAST( value AS MONEY )
```

Might be interesting to see relative performance, but I'd be surprised to see much difference.
But... probably depends on your target data type - for integer types going via MONEY might be... expensive.

*Update*

Well, it was more different than I expected - see Denis's answer.  I guess this reflects the cost of using a general-purpose function like REPLACE as compared to the more specialised CAST of VARCHAR to MONEY.

Comment: I have just stress-tested this solution and it's amazing! UH-mazing! It took only 1.5 seconds to convert and proccess 1 million `NNN,NNN,NNN` numbers from temp table with your cast-as-money-then-as-int approach. And 10.6 seconds via remove-commas approach.

Comment: select min(mn), max(mn), avg(mn)
from (
select cast(cast(n as money) as bigint) mn
from temp.money
) m --on average it takes 1.6 seconds to complete

vs.

select min(mn), max(mn), avg(mn)
from (
select cast( replace(n,',','') as bigint) mn
from temp.money
) m --on average it takes 10.6 seconds to complete

Comment: with MONEY you will lose accuracy when you are doing operations like 1.2323/4.23123

Comment: @jenny - absolutely.  Casting 'via money' has limitations - four places of decimals only and supported range -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to +922,337,203,685,477.5807.  If your input data may fall out of this range, then the technique is probably no use.  For data in range, then MONEY can be used as a 'temporary' type on the way to an exact numeric type.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace any commas with nothing and cast it as an int:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(NumberString,',','') as INT)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your existing select statement looks like this:

```
select field1 from table
```

You can use this instead to convert filed1 to a number:

```
select cast(replace(field1, ',', '') as int)  from table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select Cast(Replace(myfield, ",","") as int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just strip out the commas and do a cast:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('12,345', ',', '') AS DECIMAL(32,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you are all interested in the performance side of this issue.

Stress testing of cast-as-money-then-as-bigint approach.

Filling test data in a quick-and-dirty way:

```
;with ids as
(
select cast(abs(checksum(newid())%1000) as varchar) [1]
,cast(abs(checksum(newid())%1000) as varchar) [2]
,cast(abs(checksum(newid())%1000) as varchar) [3]
union all
select cast(abs(checksum(newid())%1000) as varchar) 
,cast(abs(checksum(newid())%1000) as varchar) 
,cast(abs(checksum(newid())%1000) as varchar) 
from ids
)
, enum as (
select [1]+','+[2]+','+[3] n, row_number() over(order by (select 0)) rn 
from ids
where len([1]) = 3 and len([2]) = 3 and len([3]) = 3
)
select rn, n
into temp.[money]
from enum
where rn <= 1000000
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Now it's time to stress test our initial approach when we want to remove all the commas from a string:

```
select min(mn), max(mn), avg(mn)
from (
select cast( replace(n,',','') as bigint) mn
from temp.money
) m
```

It takes on average 10.6 seconds to complete!

And, finally, this via-money approach:

```
select min(mn), max(mn), avg(mn)
from (
select cast(cast(n as money) as bigint) mn
from temp.money
) m
```

It takes on average 1.5 seconds to complete!